# Drag and drop dataTransfer.getData is always getting empty string

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, drop, html5-draggable

I am trying do simple drag and drop functionality. I want set some data in on drag via **dataTransfer.setData()** and get it on drop via **dataTransfer.getData()** . I am always getting empty string ("").

Please check the link for reproducing example
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-lamport-p7cqiv?file=/src/Sample.js

drag and drop and check console

**My Environment:**

Browser: **Chrome**

OS: **Windows**

**React UI library**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong event. You should use the `onDragStart` event:

```js
import React from "react";

class Abc extends React.Component {
  drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    console.log("data", data);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div id={"some_id"} onDragStart={this.drag} draggable={true}>
          Drag Me
        </div>

        <div onDragOver={this.allowDrop} onDrop={this.drop}>
          Drop On me
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Abc;
```